# Удаление из Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

У меня есть список ListView, поле для ввода и кнопка добавить. В поле я ввожу цели и добавляю их в бд в методе onClick. С бд я считую данные с помощью FirebaseListAdapter в методе displayAllGoals() и вывожу их в лист. На список я вешаю контекстное меню для редактирования и удаления. И вот мне нужно реализовать удаление через меню. Я не знаю как найти элемент из списка и удалить его из бд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.todo_activity);

listView = findViewById(R.id.items);
registerForContextMenu(listView);

myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Button btn_add = btn_add = findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText et_goal = findViewById(R.id.et_goal);
        if (et_goal.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Введите текст!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        myRef.child("Goals").child(user.getUid()).push().setValue(et_goal.getText().toString());
        et_goal.setText("");
    }
});

displayAllGoals();

  }

  @Override
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
   menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Edit");
   menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Delete");
   }

  @Override
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()){
    case 2 :
        // I need to realize this method!!!
        break;
   }
     return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
  }

    private void displayAllGoals() {
   adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String.class, R.layout.goal, 
   myRef.child("Goals").child(user.getUid())) {
       @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String s, int position) {
           TextView textView = v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText(s);
      }
   };
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);


 }
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получить позицию элемента в списке в `onContextItemSelected` можно так:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ...
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int index = info.position;
    ...
}
```

Далее используем найденый индекс для удаления:

```
DatabaseReference item=adapter.getRef(position) ;
item.removeValue();
```

Для этого потребуется `FirebaseListAdapter`. Нужно либо его сохранить при создании либо достать из `listView`:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = (FirebaseListAdapter<String>)listView.getAdapter();
```

Итого приблизительно так:

```
@Override
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()){
    case 2 :
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int index = info.position;
        FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = (FirebaseListAdapter<String>)listView.getAdapter();
        DatabaseReference item=adapter.getRef(position) ;
        item.removeValue();
        break;
   }
     return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score -1):

я не совсем понимаю вопрос, но если ты хочешь удалить данные из базы данных firebase с помощью кода, то попробуй это

```
app.database().ref('/goals/' + goalId).remove()
```

а если ты хочешь удалть данные вручную, то просто наводишь курсор на строчку которую хочешь удалить и нажимаешь на появившийся справа крестик

Comment: У меня есть список ListView, поле для ввода и кнопка добавить. В поле я ввожу цели и добавляю их в бд в методе onClick. С бд я считую данные с помощью FirebaseListAdapter в методе displayAllGoals() и вывожу их в лист. На список я вешаю контекстное меню для редактирования и удаления. И вот мне нужно реализовать удаление через меню. Я не знаю как найти элемент из списка и удалить его из бд.